# Need help refining SQL analytics function syntax - missing left parenthesis

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, window-functions

This is my query that keeps returning the error 00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis" - it indicates it should be at the line `from table b) b`. Not sure what I am doing wrong here any help is much appreciated. I am trying to select records where the address is the same and status is different.

```
select ADD.ID, ADD.Address, ADD.Unit, ADD.Status FROM
    (select b.*, min(ADD.status) OVER (partition by ADD.Address) as minstatus,
    max(ADD.status) OVER (partition by ADD.Address) as maxstatus
    from ADD b) b
     where minstatus <> maxstatus
       order by ADD.Address;
```

Ideally this would return these kind of records:

```
ID  |  Address    |  Unit | Status
1   |555 Smith Rd | Apt A | Success
2   |555 Smith Rd | Apt B | Success
3   |555 Smith Rd | Apt C | Success
4   |555 Smith Rd | Apt D | Failure
```

Comment: table ADD not selected in from clause

Comment: When I put that in there, it give me the error that my SQL command not properly ended at the 2nd line

Comment: The table I am selecting all the data from

Comment: @Panic Please confirm that Sans interpretation of your response is correct (replace `table` with `ADD`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering `add` as the table name, correct query should be -

```
SELECT c.id,
       c.address,
       c.unit,
       c.status
  FROM (SELECT b.*,
               MIN(b.status) over(PARTITION BY b.address) AS minstatus,
               MAX(b.status) over(PARTITION BY b.address) AS maxstatus
          FROM add b) c
 WHERE c.minstatus <> c.maxstatus
 ORDER BY c.address;
```